# Why my TURN server tests in js doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, turn, rfc5766turnserver

I don't understand why my TURN server tests doesn't works.

My coturn server (in a host container) : 10.200.197.74

My web server ((WSL) in a bridge container with -p 80:80 and -p 3478:3478) : 10.200.194.65

They both can ping themselves and a `turnutils_uclient 10.200.197.74 -u username -w password -y` works without any issues from the web server.

Here is the code i use to also test my server (from https://hackernoon.com/a-simple-script-to-test-whether-a-stunturn-server-is-working-properly) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test Stun/Turn Servers</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test Ice Servers</h1>

    <hr />

    <pre id='ice' style='overflow: auto'></pre>

    <hr />

    <p id='ip'></p>
    <p id='stun'> The STUN server is NOT reachable!</p>
    <p id='turn'> The TURN server is NOT reachable!</p>
    <p id='err'></p>

    <hr />

    <script>
        const Ice = document.getElementById('ice');
        const IP = document.getElementById('ip');
        const Stun = document.getElementById('stun');
        const Turn = document.getElementById('turn');
        const Err = document.getElementById('err');

        const iceServers = [
            // Test some STUN server
            {
                urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
            },
            // Test some TURN server
            {
                urls: 'turn:10.200.197.74',
                username: 'username',
                credential: 'password',
            },
        ];

        // Print iceServers config
        Ice.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(iceServers, null, 4);

        // Test the connections
        const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers
        });

        pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
            if (!e.candidate) return;

            console.log(e.candidate.candidate);

            // If a srflx candidate was found, notify that the STUN server works!
            if (e.candidate.type == 'srflx' || e.candidate.candidate.includes('srflx')) {
                let ip = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/;
                let address = e.candidate.address 
                    ? e.candidate.address 
                    : e.candidate.candidate.match(ip);
                IP.innerHTML = ' Your Public IP Address is ' + address;
                Stun.innerHTML = ' The STUN server is reachable!';
            }

            // If a relay candidate was found, notify that the TURN server works!
            if (e.candidate.type == 'relay' || e.candidate.candidate.includes('relay')) {
                Turn.innerHTML = ' The TURN server is reachable!';
            }
        };

        // handle error
        pc.onicecandidateerror = (e) => {
            console.error(e);
            Err.innerHTML = ' Error: ' + e.errorText;
        };

        pc.createDataChannel('test');
        pc.createOffer().then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The web page always return me " The TURN server is NOT reachable!"

I don't understand why because `turnutils_uclient 10.200.197.74 -u username -w password -y` works without any issues from the web server.

Here is my coTURN config file

```
listening-ip=10.214.197.74

listening-port=3478
min-port=49152
max-port=49999

verbose
lt-cred-mech
user=username:password
```

I would like that the TURN server test works in js

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from the TURN server conf file.

I added `realm=mydomain.com` to the conf file and it worked.